# Detect if a div or multiple divs are visible for the first time

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

There are multiple `div` in my page. How could I detect, that any of the `div` is visible for the first time when the page is being scrolled down.

I was trying something like:

```
$('div').offset().top() < $(window).scrollTop()
```

but surely it won't work. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Going off the first part of the answer: when something comes into view. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/825240

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    return isVisible;
}
```

This is the first step.

Now we need to have a way to see if a div has been viewed before.

```
var divWeCareAbout = document.getElementById("someDiv");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView(divWeCareAbout)){
        if(!div.dataset.haveSeen){
            //The div had scrolled into view and 
            //this is the first we have seen of it.
            //Do whatever here.
            div.dataset.haveSeen = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not to hijack this, but will this work for divs that are scrolled into view, or toggled into view with an on.click command?

Comment: @justinc As long as you have a listener for them toggled into view.